# Google is not defined when callback function called

Tags: javascript, geocoding, google-geocoder

```
function initMap() {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              ..........
            var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
              return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                label: labels[i % labels.length]
              });
            });

            // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
                {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
        }


 //Store LatLng of PostalCode
    var locations = [];

function getLatLng(zipcode, callback) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = zipcode;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            callback({lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
}

function getpc(postalcode) {

    getLatLng(postalcode, function (data) {
        locations.push({
            lat : data.lat,
            lng : data.lng
        });
        console.log("lat = " + data.lat + " and lng = " + data.lng);
    });   

}

getpc("640632");
```

When i tried to call the function getpc(), it returned google is not defined. However, if i tried to remove it, the error does not occur. I search up numerous methods to solve this but none worked. Appreciate any help.

This is the error showed on console.log :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at getLatLng (GoogleMapTest.aspx:73)
    at getpc (GoogleMapTest.aspx:88)
    at GoogleMapTest.aspx:98
```

Comment: Did you [load the Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Yes i did at the bottom after the <script> tag.  

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyABeTLZq3IydVrWOAKPgxo1lpKLlpUj4I4&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Your ReferenceError (variable not found in heap or stack) is likely due to the fact that your google maps api has not finished downloading and/or parsed yet by your webpage.

There are many benefits to loading external resources asynchronously however dependency issues like the one you're having are common.

Without knowing what your end product is you have a few options:

1. **Synchronously** load the maps api, thus ensuring when you invoke `getpc()` you can reliably assume the `google` object will be in the heap. Change  `<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…" async defer> </script>` to `<script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…"> </script>`. The Google docs suggest removing async and defer for for these reasons exactly

> In the script tag that loads the Maps JavaScript API, it is possible to omit the async attribute and the callback parameter. This will cause the loading of the API to block until the API is downloaded.

This will probably slow your page load. But it means you can write subsequent script tags assuming that the API is already loaded.

2. Keep async and defer attributes in the script tag, but instead of invoking `getpc` from your own script, supply it as the callback argument in the query param like so: `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=getpc">. If you need to invoke 2 or more functions after the maps api is loaded you could compose these into one`
3. Manually download the library using `XMLHttpRequest` and perform any subsequent routines by supplying a callback to the `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` method. [MDN handling onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)
4. (Not Recommended) replace `getpc("640632")` with `setTimeout(getpc.bind(null, '640632'), 4000)`

**UPDATE:**
It sounds like you need these routines to be ordered in such that `getpc` is invoked before `initMap`. To do this, you can you use the solution #3. Below is an example of how this would work:

```
let compose = function(fns) {
  return function() {
    while(fns.length) {
      fns.shift()();
    }
  }
};


let initmap = function() {
  console.log('Init Map');
};


let getpc = function(postalCode) {
  console.log(postalCode);
};


// pass an array of functions you want to be invoked in consecutive order
let initializationRoutines = compose([getpc.bind(null, '123'), initmap]); 

// invoke the functions one-by-one like so
initializationRoutines();

// Instead of invoking initializationRoutines, supply that as the callback to the // maps api. 
// ex: 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initializationRoutines"></script>
```

One last note, if you use this solution you will need to define `initializationRoutines` before you insert the script tag that loads the maps api like so.

```
<head>
<script>
// Compose and define your functions HERE.... Before you load the map api
let compose = function(fns) {/** ... **/};
let initmap = function() {/** .... **/};
let getpc = function(postalCode) {/** .... **/};

// pass an array of functions you want to be invoked in consecutive order
let initializationRoutines = compose(/** ARRAY_OF_FUNCTIONS**/); 
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initializationRoutines"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. and i faced one more problem which is that the lat and lng are not being pushed into the locations despite using callback.

Comment: I used console.log and found out that before getpc() has finished executing, the map has already been loaded. How can i do to get getpc() execute before the initmap()?

Comment: Or there is any other way i could do?